# Error in matlab code for matrix dimension

Tags: matlab

```
% Image Arithmetic Operations
% Image addition is done between two similar size of image, so image resize
% function is used to make size of both image same.
% I=I1+I2
clc
close all
I1=imread('test.jpg');
I2=imread('test_1.jpg');
subplot(2,2,1);imshow(I1);title('Original image I1');
subplot(2,2,2);imshow(I2);title('Original image I2');
I=I1+I2; % Addition of two images
subplot(2,2,3);imshow(I);title('Addition of image I1+I2');
I=I1-I2; % Subtraction of two images
subplot(2,2,4);imshow(I);title('Subtraction of image I1-I2');
figure;
subplot(2,2,1);imshow(I1);title('Original image I1');
I=I1+50;
subplot(2,2,2);imshow(I);title('Bright image I');
I=I1-100;
subplot(2,2,3);imshow(I);title('Dark image I');
M=imread('key.png');
M=im2bw(M); % Converts into binary image having 0s and 1s
I=uint8(I1).*uint8(M); % Type casting before multiplication
subplot(2,2,4);imshow(I);title('Masked Image I');
%clear all;
[filename,pathname]=uigetfile({'*.bmp;*.jpg;*.gif','Choose Image File'});
myimage=imread(filename);
if(size(myimage,3)==3)
    myimage=rgb2gray(myimage);
end
[Rows,Cols]=size(myimage);
newimage=zeros(Rows,Cols);
k=1;
while k<5
    for i=1:Rows
    for j=1:Cols
        if k==1
            newimage(i,j)=myimage(i,j)-100;
        end
        if k==2
            newimage(i,j)=myimage(i,j)-50;
        end
        if k==3
            newimage(i,j)=myimage(i,j)+50;
        end
        if k==4
            newimage(i,j)=myimage(i,j)+50;
        end
    end
    end
subplot(2,2,k);imshow(newimage,[]);
k=k+1;
end

% calculate mean value

[Rows,Cols]=size(myimage);
newimage=zeros(Rows,Cols);
total=0;
for i=1:Rows
    for j=1:Cols
        total=total+myimage(i,j);
    end
end
average=total/(Rows*Cols);
```

I am in big trouble because this error is not resolved and i am new to matlab coding so please help me and your solution is appreciated to me in future.
I faced an error mentioned below :

> ??? Error using ==> times Matrix dimensions must agree.
>
> Error in ==> DIP_3 at 23 I=uint8(I1).*uint8(M); % Type casting before
>   multiplication

Comment: well the error is is self-explanatory. The sizes of `l1` and `M` are different. They need to be the same if you are to multiply them together.

Comment: then tell me how can their sizes remains same

Comment: The comment at the very beginning of your code says "Image addition is done between **two similar size of image**, so **image resize function is used** to make size of both image same." (Emphasis mine.) I don't see that you resize the images anywhere to make them the same size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the three images you are working with (`test.jpg`, `test_1.jpg` and `test.png`) are of the same size, the problem arises when you call the `im2bw` function

```
M=im2bw(M);
```

The input matrix M is a 3D matrix (eg. 100x100x3) while the output matrix is only a 2D matrix (100x100).

The error is generated because you multiply matrix `I1` (which is also a 3D matrix) by a 2D matrix.

```
I=uint8(I1).*uint8(M);
```

You have therefore to make the matrix `M` a 3D matrix.

If you want to apply the same scaling factor on matrix `I1` you can do something like:

```
M=imread('key.png');
M0=im2bw(M); % Converts into binary image having 0s and 1s
M(:,:,2)=M0;
M(:,:,3)=M0;
```

Otherwise, you have to define, somehow `M(:,:,2)` and `M(:,:,3)`

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you this solution is appreciable for me and worked for me.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm happy I have been useful to you.